# AMP amp-autocomplete doesn't work in Gmail client

Tags: email, gmail, amp-form

#### Description

amp-autocomplete dropdown list doesn't render in Gmail(checked in both incognito and without any extension). The same amp-autocomplete component list is rendered in the amp official playground and gmail amp playground. However, it doesn't get displayed in actual Gmail when I send the email using my Node.js but it gets displayed when I shoot the email from the Gmail amp playground.
4 scenarios - 3 ✅  1 ❌

1. InAMP playground (https://playground.amp.dev/) ✅
   [image]
2. In Gmail AMP playground (https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/) ✅
   [image]
3. In Gmail client sent via Gmail AMP playground ✅
   [image]
4. In Gmail client sent via Nodemailer(Node.js) ❌
   [image]

This is the amp-autocomplete code

```
              <amp-autocomplete min-characters="1" src="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/autosuggest/characters" query="q">
                <input class="search" type="search" name="account_id" />
                <template type="amp-mustache">
                  <div>{{name}}</div>
                </template>
              </amp-autocomplete>
```

I am using the same API endpoint https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/autosuggest/characters for all 4 cases, so I don't know why it's not getting rendered in Gmail when I am shooting the email from my backend

#### Reproduction Steps

1. AMP playground (https://playground.amp.dev/)
2. Gmail AMP playground (https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/)
3. Create a Node.js app and use Nodemailer for sending emails.

#### Relevant Logs

```bash
VM8981:21 Could not parse event origin URL null TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
    at <anonymous>:19:31
(anonymous) @ VM8981:21
postMessage (async)
n.postMessage @ amp-viewer-integration-0.1.js:2
n.S @ amp-viewer-integration-0.1.js:2
n.sendRequest @ amp-viewer-integration-0.1.js:2
(anonymous) @ v0.js:2
(anonymous) @ v0.js:2
c @ v0.js:2
i.ut @ v0.js:2
i.sendMessage @ v0.js:2
i.flush @ v0.js:2
i.Sm @ v0.js:2
(anonymous) @ v0.js:2
u @ v0.js:2
setTimeout (async)
u @ v0.js:2
3 [amp-autocomplete] Expected a "data-value" or "data-disabled" attribute on the rendered template item. [object HTMLDivElement]
```